# What does "G" represent in acceleration?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, the-clone-wars

While reading the specs for certain clone wars fighters ([for example](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eta-2_Actis-class_interceptor)), I noticed that their maximum acceleration is measured in this G unit. I searched up what it could be, but I'm not really satisfied with the answers I got.

What does it mean by G? What does G represent in acceleration, in-universe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force. An interesting question would be what 1G is, in-universe; force of gravity on Coruscant, perhaps?

Comment: @JasonBaker this isn't anywhere near definitive, but judging by what I remember seeing in the movies and the general humanoid shape of most species prevalent in Star Wars, I'd say that most populated planets in Star Wars probably have a surface gravity in the ballpark of 10 m/s^2

Comment: Judging by how fast the floating rocks on Dagobah drop when Luke loses his concentration, I'd say it's exactly "9.80665 metres per second squared, or equivalently 9.80665 newtons of force per kilogram of mass."

Comment: [What does it mean to find acceleration in terms of g?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52343/what-does-it-mean-to-find-acceleration-in-terms-of-g)

Comment: Coruscant gravity is most likely, as they base all of their standards off of coruscant, if not, Alderaan.

Comment: @Mazura You joke, but there was a Superman question with an answer involving math done on framerates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is a description of the [g-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force) provided by the ship's engines, essentially how fast the ship can reach its top speed and how heavy the ship will become during that period of [linear acceleration](http://www.tutorvista.com/physics/linear-acceleration-equation)

In this instance, with a max acceleration of 5.2g and a top speed of approx 1500Km/h in atmosphere, the ship will reach max velocity (from a standing start) in just over 8 seconds.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[g-Acceleration Calculator - Linear Motion](https://rechneronline.de/g-acceleration/)</sup></sub>

By comparison, a modern (Earth) jet fighter might reach as much as *1g* of linear acceleration and could take 45 seconds or more to reach 1500Km/h.

---

For the record, fighter ships in the Star Wars universe do appear to experience g-forces, but vastly less so than you'd expect, indicating that they're using some form of gravity-dampening technology to protect the pilot.

Comment: This is not satisfying, because we don't even know what a g-force *is* in-universe. What planet in the wide, wide galaxy is it based off of?

Comment: They're probably basing it off of coruscant's gravity, like they do with everything else.

Comment: @Dbpriguy - Almost certainly Coruscant. It's what other measurements (hours, days, years, etc) seem to come from.

Answer (score 2):

1g is a fairly common way of denoting acceleration, particularly in respect to the tolerances of the human body.

On earth 1g is 9.8m/s/s this is the constant aceleraion due to gravity which we all feel all the time, although we don't always interpret this as a force or acceleration as we as used to it so a more useful analogy is that its is the acceleration you feel if you jump off a ledge.

In terms of tolerance and what it 'feels' like a typical car may generate 1g of acceleration under very heavy braking. High performance racing cars may develop maybe 3-5 g as a sustained force.

The most agile fighter jets can sustain perhaps about 10 g in a turn but this is certainly well into the limit of what a fit and conditioned human can tolerate before blacking out.

For impacts 30 g is a generally accepted limit of what is reasonably survivable but there are plenty of incidences of for example F1 drivers surviving 40g+ peak impact forces with few ill effects.

Answer (score 0):

A "G" is a unit equivalent of earth's gravity. 
 For example, right now the earth is exerting one G of downward force on you.  If a ship has 5 Gs of acceleration, that means the pilot will feel 5 times the force of gravity pressing back, unless there is some sort of apparatus that affects the Gs.  I hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) This seems like a pretty good and succinct explanation of how we use the term in the real world and it only makes sense that that's what it means in Star Wars. But. *Is* that what it means in Star Wars? I mean, I assume it is, too, but this is a sci-fi and fantasy Q&A site, so if there's any way for you to confirm that this is definitely how it's used in Star Wars (primary or secondary sources) that would certainly help. I think so, anyway :P

Comment: Minor point: the unit of gravitational acceleration is normally "g". "G" is technically the relationship between inertial mass (how hard you have to push something to get it moving) and gravitational mass (how strongly two masses attract due to their mutual gravity). However when someone says "5.2G" its just that they don't know the difference.